# Parse date string to Date object when loading Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: json, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

When I render form using data received from the server, there is problem with datetime fields. My input datepicker looks like this:

```
<form name="itemForm">
    <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="startedAt" name="startedAt"
           ng-model="item.startedAt"
           ng-click="open($event, 'startedAt')"
           uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
           is-open="datepickers.startedAt"
    />
</form>
```

My server returns response datetime as JSON string:

```
{    
   ...
   startedAt: "2015-05-29T02:00:00+0200"
}
```

When I assign response data to the model `$scope.item = response;`, datepicker input field is rendered correctly (correct date is selected and it's properly formatted in format I selected). The problem is that validation does not pass. I get:

```
itemForm.startedAt.$invalid == true
```

I noticed that data bound to the datepicker field should be `Date` object and not string (when I select new date from the datepicker, `$scope.item.startedAt` is a `Date`)

I managed to work around this issue and do this in the controller:

```
$scope.item = response;
$scope.item.startedAt = new Date($scope.item.startedAt);
```

It works this way... But I wouldn't like to manually convert string do date every time I get a response from the server. I tried to create a directive, that I can assign to the datepicker input field so it converts the `ng-model` for me:

```
.directive("asDate", function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

            modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (input) {

                var transformedInput = new Date(input);

                if (transformedInput != input) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }

                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Well it works, because now I can see `Date` object, when I output model in my view: `{{item.startedAt}}`. However still **validation fails**! I suspect this is some problem with me understanding how data flows between model and the view, and how UI Bootstrap hooks into it.

Also when I change my directive from `$formatters.push` to `$formatters.unshift`, validation works OK, but datepicker does not format my datetime (insted of nicely formattet `yyyy-MM-dd` I see ISO string inside the input)

Comment: Aww man we are having the exact same problem here!!!

Comment: @VictorParmar currently I'm doing this the way around - converting response string to Date object when receiving from server. And converting Date object to string when sending to server. All this done in Angular controller manually. Maybe I will just extract this logic as Angular service, but I don't think its possible to do with directive

Comment: yeah join the club - we ended up doing the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is intentional behaviour of angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4690), I ended up using Angular service/factory and `moment` library.

Service `dateConverter` can be injected globally to intercept all HTTP requestes/responses or only in desired controllers.

Here I use `Restangular` library to handle request to REST API, hence the `response.plain()` method which takes only object properties, and not Restangular methods/properties.

```
var Services = angular.module('app.Services', []);

Services
    .factory('dateConverter', ['dateFilter', function (dateFilter) {

        var dateConverter = {};

        dateConverter.prepareResponse = function (response) {
            for(prop in response.plain()) {
                if (response.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if(moment(response[prop], moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()) {
                        response[prop] = new Date(response[prop]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return response;
        };

        dateConverter.prepareRequest = function (item) {
            for(prop in item.plain()) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if(angular.isDate(item[prop])){
                         item[prop] = dateFilter(item[prop] , "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
                    }
                }
            }
            return item;
        };

        return dateConverter;
    }])
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This broke as of Angular.UI.Bootstrap v0.13.2 (8-2-2015)
Downgrading to 0.13.1 works, which is where I'm stuck today.

Wesleycho says this was done intentionally
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4690

I'm ready for other date pickers that support strings if anyone has a suggestion

...soon after posting this I went down a non-angular path that I'm not proud of, but it works for both HTML5 type="date" and uib-datepicker-popup.  I have a regular expression that determines if a string resembles one of the two serialized date formats I've seen, and then I have a recursive javascript function to traverse a json tree and replace those strings with Date().  You would call it just before you put in $scope (or viewmodel) ...

```
$http.get("../api/comm/" + commId
    ).success(function (resp) {
        fixDates(resp);
        vm.comm = resp;
    });
```

(I need not check the string length, but I figured it would spare some cpu cycles by not running the regex if the string is obviously not a date)

```
//2015-10-01T00:00:00-04:00
//2015-11-20T18:15:56.6229516-05:00
var isDate = new RegExp("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}(\\.\\d{7})?-\\d{2}:00");

function fixDates(json) {
    for (i in json)
        if (typeof (json[i]) == "object")
            fixDates(json[i]);
        else if (typeof (json[i]) == "string" && (json[i].length == 25 || json[i].length == 33) && isDate.test(json[i]))
            json[i] = new Date(json[i]);
};
```

Comment: when you are using javascript for-in loop you probable should also use hasOwnProperty()

Answer (score 1):

you can transform String to Date in restangular transformer, something like this

```
RestangularConfigurer
  .addElementTransformer('<RESTRESOURCENAME>', false, function (element) {
      element.createDate = new Date(element.createDate);
      return element;
  })
```

Comment: Any guidance how to use it?